# Why am i getting NaN while multipling select data-attrib with input value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am having issues to get total for my `<span class="cubics"></span>`. I am getting NaN as my result when i input value to my `<input class="item_unit" value="">` and multiply with select `data-cubics`

Here is my code

PHP To populate select options

```
foreach($result as $row)
{
  $output .= '<option value="'.$row["unit_name"].'" data-cubics="'.$row["unit_price"].'" >'.$row["unit_name"].'</option>';
}
```

TABLE to display results

```
<table class="table table-bordered" id="item_table">
      <tr>
       <th>Enter Quantity</th>
       <th>Select Unit</th>
       <th>Total</th>
       <th><button type="button" name="add" class="btn btn-success btn-sm add"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></button></th>
      </tr>

     </table>
     <tr class="bg">
            <td width="33%">TOTAL</td>
            <td width="33%"><span id="totalquantity"></span>

            </td>
             <td width="33%">TOTAL</td>
            <td width="33%"><span class="totalcubics"></span>

            </td>
        </tr>
```

JAVASCRIPT To handle functionality

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

 $(document).on('click', '.add', function(){
  var html = '';
  html += '<tr>';
  html += '<td><select name="item_unit[]" class="item_unit form-control"><option value="">Select Unit</option><?php echo fill_unit_select_box($connect); ?></select></td>';
  html += '<td><input class="qty form-control" type="text" value="0"/></td>';
  html += '<td width="33%"><span class="cubics"></span>';
  html += '<td><button type="button" name="remove" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm remove"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span></button></td></tr>';
 $('#item_table').append(html);
  $summands = $form.find('input.qty'); //***************  add this line
 });

 $(document).on('click', '.remove', function(){
  $(this).closest('tr').remove();
 });

 $('#insert_form').on('submit', function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  var error = '';

  $('.qty').each(function(){
   var count = 1;
   if($(this).val() == '')
   {
    error += "<p>Enter Item Quantity at "+count+" Row</p>";
    return false;
   }
   count = count + 1;
  });

  $('.item_unit').each(function(){
   var count = 1;
   if($(this).val() == '')
   {
    error += "<p>Select Unit at "+count+" Row</p>";
    return false;
   }
   count = count + 1;
  });

 });

});


function total() {
    var total1 = 0;
    $('span.cubics').each(function () {
        var n = parseFloat($(this).text());
        total1 += isNaN(n) ? 0 : n;
    });
    $('.totalcubics').text(total1.toFixed(2));
}

$(document).on('keyup' , 'input.qty' , function () {
    var val = parseFloat($(this).val());
    val = (val ? val * $(this).data('cubics') : '');
   $(this).closest('td').next().find('span.cubics').text(val);
    total();
});

var $form = $('#insert_form'),
    $summands = $form.find('input.qty'),
    $sumDisplay = $('span#totalquantity');



$form.keyup(function () {
    var sum = 0;
    $summands.each(function () {
        var value = Number($(this).val());
        if (!isNaN(value)) sum += value;
    });

    $sumDisplay.text(sum);
});

$('input').on({
    focus: function () {
        if (this.value == '0') this.value = '';
    },
    blur: function () {
        if (this.value === '') this.value = '0';
    }
});


         $(function() {
  $('.qty').change(function() {
    var p = $(this).parent().parent()
    var m = p.find('input.qty')
    var mul = parseInt($(m[0]).val()).toFixed(2)
    var res = p.find('.qty')
    res.html(mul);
    var total = 0;
    $('.qty').each(function() {
      total += parseInt($(this).text());
    })
    parseInt(total).toFixed(2);
    $('.cubics').html(parseInt(total).toFixed(2));
  });
});

$('.item_unit').change(calcVal);

function calcVal() {
  $(".cubics").html($(this).children(':checked').data('cubics') * $('input.qty').text().trim())
}

// call on document load
calcVal();
</script>
```

Sorry couldn't narrow it down to the culprit lines. `html += '<td width="33%"><span class="cubics"></span>';` is getting `NaN` as result

SELECT OPTIONS generated by PHP

```
<td><select name="item_unit[]" class="item_unit form-control">
<option value="">Select Unit</option>
<option value="Bags" data-cubics="40000" >Bags</option>
<option value="Bottles" data-cubics="20000" >Bottles</option>
<option value="Box" data-cubics="30000" >Box</option>
<option value="Dozens" data-cubics="90000" >Dozens</option>
</select></td>
```

Comment: In that line you forgot the `</td>`.

Comment: Post a runnable example please.  The javascript is referencing elements that don't exist in your html.

Comment: @James to my best of knowledge, everything is referenced as is per my code, i wish i could narrow down to the exact code that is giving me issues but unfortunately, i can't, kindly perouse through and find me a solution

Comment: You need to do some more debugging and narrow down where that error occurs. This is a code equivalent of "where's Waldo".

Comment: You should also indent your code properly and consistently. The first part of your JS has one space indention. That makes the code pretty unreadable. You also have a `$(function()) { ... }` inside a `$(document).ready(function() { ... })`. That's just two different syntax for the same thing.

Comment: Lets assume the php works.  Can you post the <options> that are generated by it?  I'm not going to pore through your javascript looking for bugs by eye, but I will run something that doesn't quite work but is complete, and offer suggestions on how to fix it.

Comment: @James i have added the <options> to the question

Comment: @James i suspect `function calcVal() {` is being overwritten by `$(document).on('keyup' , 'input.qty' , function () {` probably you can help me from there